# Can't figure out how to get my pine script code to have three different time charts to evaluate

Tags: algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script

I am currently using this code for my strategy. I have my alerts all set up but the problem is I am looking at when the 1 day, 5 day and 30 day chart %D all fall below 17.5 so whenever I get an alert for one I have to go manually check were the other ones are at. Is there any way to redo some code to where the alert will only be sent if the %D line falls below for all three charts?

I believe this can be done with the security() function but I cant exactly figure it out. My idea is to have the amd_1, amd_5, amd_30 and calculate D for all three and have those three plotted in the chart and then set up and alert saying if D1 < 17.5 and D5 < 17.5 and D30 < 17.5 then send the alert. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
//@version=4
strategy("stochastic")

amd_1 = security("NYSE:AMD", "1D", close)
amd_5 = security("NYSE:AMD", "5D", close)
amd_30 = security("NYSE:AMD", "30D", close)

length = input(21, minval=1, title="length")  
rsilength = input(21, minval=1, title="rsi length")  
smoothk = input(4, minval=1, title="smoothk")
smoothd = input(10, minval=1, title="smoothd")
showMarkers = input(true, "Show Markers")

rsi = rsi(close, rsilength)

sto = stoch(close,highest(length),lowest(length), length)
K = sma(sto,smoothk)
D = sma(K,smoothd)

//plot(rsi, title="rsi", color=color.black)
plot(D, title="%D",color=color.green)
plot(K, title="%K",color=color.red)

hline(78,title="upper limit", color=color.red)
hline(17, title="lower limit",color=color.blue)
//plot(sto, title = "sto",color=color.black)


// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
FromMonth = input(defval = 8, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
FromDay   = input(defval = 24, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2019, title = "From Year", minval = 2017)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 9, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
ToDay     = input(defval = 1, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
ToYear    = input(defval = 9999, title = "To Year", minval = 2017)

// === FUNCTION EXAMPLE ===
start     = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false // create function "within window of time"

// === EXECUTION ===
shares = 10000/close
buy = crossunder(D,17.5)
sell = crossover(D,78)

strategy.entry("buy", shares, when = window() and buy)  // buy long when "within window of time" AND crossover
strategy.close("buy", when = window() and sell)         // sell long when "within window of time" AND crossunder

plotshape(showMarkers and buy, "buy", shape.triangleup, location.bottom, color.green, 0, text = "buy", size = size.tiny)
plotshape(showMarkers and sell, "sell", shape.triangledown, location.top, color.maroon, 0, text = "sell", size = size.tiny)
bgcolor(showMarkers ? window() ? color.green : color.maroon : na)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to change your os/ob levels and dates to get a signal as your criteria are very strict. Also added some marker and background code so you can uncomment to see different conditions. You have the option of using repainting or no repainting on higher timeframe lines:

```
//@version=4
strategy("stochastic")

length = input(21, minval=1, title="length")  
rsilength = input(21, minval=1, title="rsi length")  
smoothk = input(4, minval=1, title="smoothk")
smoothd = input(10, minval=1, title="smoothd")
showMarkers = input(true, "Show Markers")
repaint = input(false, "Repaint Higher Timeframes")
showD1 = input(true, "Show 1 Day D")
showD2 = input(true, "Show 5 Day D")
showD3 = input(true, "Show 1 Month D")
obLevel = input(70)
osLevel = input(60)

rsi = rsi(close, rsilength)
sto = stoch(close,highest(length),lowest(length), length)
K = sma(sto,smoothk)
D = sma(K,smoothd)

d1 = repaint ? security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", D) : security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", D[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
d2 = repaint ? security(syminfo.tickerid, "5D", D) : security(syminfo.tickerid, "5D", D[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
d3 = repaint ? security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", D) : security(syminfo.tickerid, "30D", D[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(showD1 ? d1 : na, "D 1D", color.aqua)
plot(showD2 ? d2 : na, "D 5D", color.blue)
plot(showD3 ? d3 : na, "D 30D", color.purple)

//plot(rsi, title="rsi", color=color.black)
plot(D, title="%D",color=color.green)
plot(K, title="%K",color=color.red)

hline(obLevel,title="upper limit", color=color.red)
hline(osLevel, title="lower limit",color=color.blue)
//plot(sto, title = "sto",color=color.black)


// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
FromMonth = input(defval = 8, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
FromDay   = input(defval = 24, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
FromYear  = input(defval = 2000, title = "From Year", minval = 2017)
ToMonth   = input(defval = 9, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
ToDay     = input(defval = 1, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
ToYear    = input(defval = 9999, title = "To Year", minval = 2017)
// === FUNCTION EXAMPLE ===
start     = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false // create function "within window of time"

// === EXECUTION ===
shares = 10000/close
var inLong  = false
buy = false
sell = false
buyTrigger  = d1 < osLevel and d2 < osLevel and d3 < osLevel
sellTrigger = d1 > obLevel and d2 > obLevel and d3 > obLevel
if buyTrigger and not inLong and window()
    buy     := true
    inLong  := true
else
    if sellTrigger and inLong and window()
        sell    := true
        inLong  := false

strategy.entry("buy", shares, when = buy)  // buy long when "within window of time" AND crossover
strategy.close("buy", when = sell)         // sell long when "within window of time" AND crossunder

plotshape(showMarkers and buy, "buy", shape.triangleup, location.bottom, color.green, 0, text = "buy", size = size.tiny)
plotshape(showMarkers and sell, "sell", shape.triangledown, location.top, color.maroon, 0, text = "sell", size = size.tiny)
// plotshape(showMarkers and buyTrigger, "buyTrigger", shape.triangleup, location.bottom, color.green, 0, text = "buyTrigger", size = size.tiny)
// plotshape(showMarkers and sellTrigger, "sellTrigger", shape.triangledown, location.top, color.maroon, 0, text = "sellTrigger", size = size.tiny)
// bgcolor(showMarkers ? buyTrigger ? color.green : sellTrigger ? color.maroon : na : na)
bgcolor(showMarkers ? inLong ? color.green : color.maroon : na)
// bgcolor(showMarkers ? window() ? color.green : color.maroon : na)
```

[image]

This is a one month chart with d1 and d2 plots disabled and *Repaint Higher Timeframes* unchecked:

[image]

Same chart with *Repaint Higher Timeframes* checked. Two things happen: you can see the d3 purple line fit you current TF green D line, confirming it is correct. Entries/exits happen earlier, as repainting version of higher TF line is not delayed.

[image]

Comment: That is awesome, thank you. I do have some questions though. So it looks like the d1, d2 and d3 lines should be plotting the %D line for each respective time frame. I think they maybe are but in your graph I see you are looking at years of data. When I was doing this I was just looking at the 1, 5 and 30 day graphs and the %D indicator crosses 20 and 80 quite a lot in a week. I do not think these are actually plotting the %D line correctly for each time frame because if you go down and look at a month the lines will mostly be straight when they should be oscillating. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: I edited the line for d3. Resolution should've been `"1M"`—not `"30D"`, so you'll need to change that line. Your d1, d2 and d3 lines are the actual ones from the higher timeframes. You can verify this easily, since you have the D line for the current TF plotting in green. Just go to 1D, 5D and 1M timeframes, click the *Repaint Higher Timeframes* checkbox in the script's *Settings/Inputs* to allow the higher TF lines to repaint, and you'll see the D line from the `security()` call matching the current TF green plot.

Comment: Hey, sorry I am new at this so I may be missing something. I checked the box to let it repaint from higher time frames and those lines are still straight. So what are the other lines supposed to be exactly? I thought they were (say you were on the 1 day chart) they would be the 5 day and 1 month %D lines. So they would mirror. If I changed over to the 5 day chart then it would be the same as the green line on their. Thanks

Comment: I changed your code so you can selectively plot d1, d2 and d3 and show you how d3 does match the actual 1 month D line. Higher TF lines have long flat areas on lower TFs because they don't change often, being from a higher TF. The d1 line, for example, will always have the same value on all the 1H bars of any given day, since it's fetched from the 1D TF.